# autohot key using Text Box and a button

Tags: autohotkey

Need a little help with a text box and a button..

I have been trying to experiment with "text box" and a "button"..but am not able to do it... I need to take the "values" from the "textbox" field and append it to the button action. i.e., whatever the input is given by the user... need to append it to a "URL"

Example:

If the user is types in "login" as input in the text field, need to take this input and append it to "http://www.google.com/login"

Before action:
http://google.com

AfterAction:
http://google.com/login

Kindly help

Here is my Code:

```
Gui, Add, Edit, x162 y80 w140 h30 vUserInput, Type here
Gui, Add, Button, x182 y130 w100 h30 gAction, %"Action1" Action1:=http://www.google.om/
; Generated using SmartGUI Creator 4.0
Gui, Show, x127 y87 h379 w479, New GUI Window
Return

Action1:
Gui, Submit, NoHide
guiControlGet, txtVar,, UserInput
guiControl,, UserInput, %( txt++Action1 )

GuiClose:
ExitApp
return
```

Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, you have a few misconceptions and a LOT of errors.
The use of `:=` -vs- `%` is one of your misunderstandings.

Also, you neglected to put `gAction1` as the goto label for your button.  You had `gAction`, but there was no sub called `Action`.

Another problem is that you have not placed `return` at the end of your `Action1` label.
That means that after the action is completed, the script will continue on to end the script...

You should **really** read the AutoHotkey Documentation!  It will save you a lot of time and headache.  Also, you should look at some simple examples.

However, try the script below.  Whatever you type into the box, after you push the button, will be appended to the url.

---

```
;Now, it may be easier to define your re-usable variable here like this:
;myurl = http://www.google.com/
myurl := "http://www.google.com/"       ;this is exactly same as the previous line

Gui, Add, Edit, x162 y80 w300 h30 r1 vUserInput, Type here
Gui, Add, Button, x182 y130 w100 h30 gAction1, Action1      ;The last parameter is JUST the text on the button
;If you wanted to use a variable for the name instead of straight text, you would do this:
;Gui, Add, Button, x182 y130 w100 h30 gAction, %myurl%
;But what you were trying to do is to *assign* a variable instead of *using* a variable - that is, you CAN'T use action1:=value as the variable name

Gui, Show, x127 y87 h379 w479, New GUI Window
Return

Action1:  ;the name of this label is the same as the g-action of your button except without the "g" part.
    Gui, Submit, NoHide
    guiControlGet, UserInput        ;you can simply use the edit control's v-name as the output variable
    thisurl = %myurl%%UserInput%
    guiControl,,UserInput, %thisurl%    ;now set the url back to the control
return  ;if you don't put return here, the script will continue on and run the GuiClose label...

GuiClose:
    ExitApp
return  ;you can have this, but you don't need it here since the script will have ended before it gets run anyway.
```